# Proving $\ker(T) = \ker(T^*)$ and $\operatorname{range}(T) = \operatorname{range}(T^*)$ for normal operator T

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Also, we have that $T:V \rightarrow V$ is a linear operator. Here, $T^*$ is the adjoint of $T$.
I am unsure how to continue my proof.
I've claimed that $\|T(v)\| = \|T^*(v)\|$ and have proven my claim, but not sure how to continue from there.
Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\|Tv\| = \|T^*v\|, \forall v \in V$ we have
$$v \in \ker T \iff Tv = 0 \iff \|Tv\| = 0 \iff \|T^*v\| = 0 \iff T^*v = 0 \iff v \in \ker T^*$$

so $\ker T = \ker T^*$.

Now we can also conclude

$$\operatorname{range} T  = (\ker T^*)^\perp = (\ker T)^\perp = \operatorname{range} T^*$$

Comment: Isn't $(\operatorname{Ker}T)^\perp=\overline{\operatorname{Ran}T^*}$?

Comment: @HritRoy Yes but here in the context of linear algebra we have $\overline{\operatorname{Ran} T^*} = \operatorname{Ran} T^* $. The claim for Hilbert spaces is proved here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1347338/144766